# Possibillity to create decorator from a class

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it was possible to create a property decorator from a class with TypeScript 1.5 ? I mean switching from

```
 function Inject(value = null) {
    return function (target:Object, propertyKey:string) {
        target[propertyKey] = value;
    };
}
```

to a class like

```
class Inject{...}
```

?

How can we do if it's possible ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

From the [TypeScript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#decorators) (and from the decorator proposal):

A decorator is:

- an expression
- that evaluates to a function
- that takes the target, name, and property descriptor as arguments
- and optionally returns a property descriptor to install on the target object

So, no.  You could however implement the logic of the decorator with any sort of code you want which could include logic encapsulated in a class.

Answer (score 0):

An example of creating a decorator within a class:

```
class MyDecorators {

  static aDecorator(someValue: string) {
    return this.decorate;
  }

  static decorate(target: any) {
    target.hello = 'world';
  }
}

@MyDecorators.aDecorator()
class DecoratedClass {
}
```

This could be helpful if you only want a way to group decorators together.